Field propagation in metamaterial based optical fibres?
We have an optical fibre having HMM cladding ( $\mu=1$ and have a permittivity tensor with one component different in sign than others) and a core having permittivity equal to one. How will light propagate in this fibre using total internal reflection or some other phenomenon?

In this fiber with a negative-permittivity cladding (HMM) and a core with permittivity ε = 1. light propagation won't rely on total internal reflection (TIR),  instead light propagation occurs via surface plasmon polaritons (SPPs). SPPs arise from the coupling of light with the cladding's electrons, leading to a wave that propagates along the interface between the core (ε = 1) and the cladding.
